# genymotion: it does not show the virtual box content inside mymotion emulator

Tags: android-studio, genymotion

I have installed genymotion emulator to the android studio but when I run the emulator it does not show it's content inside the emulator.
when I opened the virual box it is content was loaded inside the the virual box.

here is the image:

[image]